# DataList inside ItemTemplate disappears after AsyncPostBackTrigger

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, datalist, data-synchronization

I have a datalist which occurs inside an ItemTempate for another datalist.
The datalist I have a problem with is a UserControl which appears inside the parent DataList's ItemTemplate.

**The Problem**: When clicking the "Add comment" button, the code behind **does** run and the page does not refresh, as expected, but the DataList **disappears completely** !

Here is the UserControl HTML:

```
    <asp:DataList   ID="DataListComments" 
                    runat="server"
                    OnItemCommand="DataListComments_ItemCommand" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceComments">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="CommentItemDIV_<%#Eval("Comment_ID")%>">
                <table><tr>
                    <td style="width:1px;">
                        <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("Comment_ID")%>' CssClass="Invisible" ID="lblCommentID" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:20px;">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteComment" runat="server" CssClass="btnCircleSmall btnTrash" CommandName="DeleteComment" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:9px;"></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("Comment_Text")%></td>
                </tr></table>
            </div>
            <hr class="UltraThinHR" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList> 

</ContentTemplate>



<triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DataListComments" EventName="ItemCommand" />
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddComment"  EventName="Click" />
</triggers>
```

Here is the element which triggers the new comment insert:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddComment" class="btnAdd" OnClick="btnAddComment_Click" />
```

Here is the code behind the button click:

```
DataUtils.CreateComment("dsds");
DataListComments.DataBind();
```

Comment: may be you also have to point DataSource in code behind?

Comment: Tried that, it does not solve the problem.